# python coding of user input of hex numerals

Tags: python

How do I get the A to F hex numerals in as user input via something like:

`hexnum=raw_input("input your hex number -> ")`

Then I have a problem with such input not being convertible via:

`number=int(hexnum)`

I am looking for a simple example with a basic explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The `int` constructor takes a base as its optional second argument.

```
>>> int('12AF', 16)
4783
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work fine.  Just inform *[int](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int)* that it is working with base 16: `int(hexnum, 16)`.

```
>>> hexnum = raw_input("input your hex number -> ")
input your hex number -> 2F
>>> print int(hexnum, 16)
47
```